# UPDATE table with WHERE multiple condition from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

**users**

```
| id | amount | 
---------------
| 1  | 10     | 
| 2  | 20.50  | 
| 3  | 0      | 
| 4  | 80     | 
| 5  | 0      | 
---------------
```

**vehicle_travel**

```
| id | user_id | costprice | status  |
--------------------------------------
| 1  | 1       | 80.00     | active  |
| 2  | 1       | 20.00     | expired |
| 3  | 2       | 130.50    | active  |
| 4  | 5       | 325.00    | active  |
| 5  | 3       | 99.50     | expired |
--------------------------------------
```

I want to `UPDATE` **users table** and `SET` **users.amount** to **users.amount+vehicle_travel.costprice** `WHERE` the **users.id** equals to **vehicle_travel.user_id** `AND` **vehicle_travel.status** equals to **'expired'**

This is my full query:

```
UPDATE users 
SET users.amount=users.amount+vehicle_travel.costprice 
WHERE users.id=vehicle_travel.user_id 
AND vehicle_travel.status='expired'
```

But i keep getting **unknown column** errors from phpMyAdmin.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide exact error messages

Comment: need to use `join`

Comment: it depends on how many expired you could have per userid. So, that info drives whether the answers below are going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;)

```
UPDATE users 
INNER JOIN vehicle_travel
ON users.id = vehicle_travel.user_id
AND vehicle_travel.status = 'expired'
SET users.amount = users.amount + vehicle_travel.costprice
```

***EDITED:***

```
UPDATE users 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(costprice) AS costprice, user_id
    FROM vehicle_travel
    WHERE status = 'expired'
    GROUP BY user_id
) vehicle_travel
ON users.id = vehicle_travel.user_id
SET users.amount = users.amount + vehicle_travel.costprice
```

Comment: It works now but if there is 2 or more vehicle_travel with the status 'expired' it only adds the first vehicle_travel.costprice to the users.amount but not the second. How can i achieve this?

Comment: @JeremyJohn For this case, you need a sub query to `sum(costprice)`, check the ***Edited*** answer please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `JOIN`. If you don't specify the table name you will encounter **unknown column error** for those columns referring to the unspecified table.

```
UPDATE users 
INNER JOIN vehicle_travel ON vehicle_travel.user_id = users.id
SET users.amount=users.amount+vehicle_travel.costprice 
WHERE vehicle_travel.status='expired'
```